# No visible interface declare the select , even if the method is implemented

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

I create a pdf and i want to have a table in it . I found a tutorial [draw pdf with table](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6818/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2) , but after i implent this method :

```
+(void)drawTableAt:(CGPoint)origin
     withRowHeight:(int)rowHeight
    andColumnWidth:(int)columnWidth
       andRowCount:(int)numberOfRows
    andColumnCount:(int)numberOfColumns

{
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfRows; i++)
    {
        int newOrigin = origin.y + (rowHeight*i);

        CGPoint from = CGPointMake(origin.x, newOrigin);
        CGPoint to = CGPointMake(origin.x + (numberOfColumns*columnWidth), newOrigin);

        [self drawLineFromPoint:from toPoint:to];
    }
}


and  when i call it in :

    (void)generatePdf:(NSString *)filePath{

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(filePath, CGRectZero, nil);
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792), nil);

        [self drawBackground];
        [self  drawCamionContext];


        int xOrigin = 50;
        int yOrigin = 300;

        int rowHeight = 50;
        int columnWidth = 120;

        int numberOfRows = 7;
        int numberOfColumns = 4;

        [self drawTableAt:CGPointMake(xOrigin, yOrigin) withRowHeight:rowHeight andColumnWidth:columnWidth andRowCount:numberOfRows andColumnCount:numberOfColumns];
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    }
```

I have an error : no visible interface declare the selector "drawTableAt...."

I declare this methos also in h file..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you declared `drawTableAt:...` as a static method (using the **+**) on your class.

Just change `+(void)drawTableAt:(CGPoint)origin` to `-(void)drawTableAt:(CGPoint)origin` and it should work (keep in mind to change that in the header too!)